# When I am trying to run nopcommerc 4.10 project I am getting error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nopcommerce

When I am trying to run `nopcommerc 4.10` project at that time I am getting this type of error:

> ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the
>   requested types. Could not load type 'System.Net.ICertificatePolicy'
>   from assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

```
System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator<TSource, TResult>.ToArray()
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
AutoMapper.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapperClasses(IServiceCollection services, Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression> additionalInitAction, IEnumerable<Assembly> assembliesToScan)
Nop.Core.Infrastructure.NopEngine.AddAutoMapper(IServiceCollection services, ITypeFinder typeFinder) in NopEngine.cs

                services.AddAutoMapper();

Nop.Core.Infrastructure.NopEngine.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration) in NopEngine.cs

                AddAutoMapper(services, typeFinder);

Nop.Web.Framework.Infrastructure.Extensions.ServiceCollectionExtensions.ConfigureApplicationServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfigurationRoot configuration) in ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

                var serviceProvider = engine.ConfigureServices(services, configuration);

Nop.Web.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in Startup.cs

                return services.ConfigureApplicationServices(Configuration);

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

Please Help me.

Thanks, Ugresh.

Comment: It's working without any issue, it's targeting SDK 2.1, you need to install it first.

Answer (score 1):

I think some of your dll is not compatible with asp.net core.

because nopcommerce 4.10 is targeting dot net core.

So, please double check.

did you use third party dll?